# Apache: how to create subdomain on name-based virtualhost?

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, subdomain

i have name-based hosting, lets name it `my.address.com` - my friend have 'white' ip -`address.com` and gave me virtual machine than i can access via ssh, also, he made some magic with ports and now after install apache i could access /var/www on the `my.address.com`. 
So, the question is how can i make subdomain like `test.my.address.com`? There are should be some magick with [Apache's Listen Directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mpm_common.html#listen), but i cant figure it finally.
Also, i know how to create local-available sites with apache, but it is not the same.

Answer (score 2):

First you have to modify the DNS zone and add a record for `test.my.address.com` to point to the server's IP address.

Then, you just add another `<VirtualHost>` directive or a `ServerAlias` directive into an existing `<VirtualHost>` if you want the subdomain to point to the same virtual host.

I suggest you read the [Apache tutorial on name-based virtual hosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/name-based.html).